# replace header in a file with list of lines in another file

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a fasta file contained ~28000 sequence. I want to replace header of these sequences by a list of lines in another file.
Example:

File 1:

```
sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27
MPIGNLGNNVNGNHLIPPAPP.....
sp|P0ACF8|HNS_ECOLI
MSEALKILNNIRTLRAQ........
sp|P24232|HMP_ECOLI
MLDAQTIATVKATIPLLVET..........
```

File 2:

```
sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27OS=Escherichia coli
sp|P0ACF8|HNS_ECOLI=Human
sp|P24232|HMP_ECOLI=Flavohemoprotein
```

Desired Output:

```
sp|B7UM99|TIR_ECO27OS=Escherichia coli
MPIGNLGNNVNGNHLIPPAPP.....
sp|P0ACF8|HNS_ECOLI=Human
MSEALKILNNIRTLRAQ........
sp|P24232|HMP_ECOLI=Flavohemoprotein
MLDAQTIATVKATIPLLVET..........
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the script below is what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Save the good lines
awk '{if($0 !~ "^sp")print > "result_1" }' < file_1
awk '{if($0 ~ "^sp")print > "result_2" }' < file_2

# Get number of lines in result_1 ( == nl in result_2 )
nl_file=$(wc -l result_1|cut -d' ' -f1)

# Prepare sorting of these files preceded by a number
seq 2 2 $(( ${nl_file} * 2 )) > numbered_file_1
seq 1 2 $(( ${nl_file} * 2 )) > numbered_file_2

# paste content of numbered_file_* and result_* side by side
paste -d ' ' numbered_file_1 result_1 > mergedfiles
paste -d ' ' numbered_file_2 result_2 >> mergedfiles

sort -n mergedfiles | sed 's/^[[:digit:]]\s\+//g'
```